# Сохранить состояние Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-architecture

Есть фрагмент в котором находится карта. Использую Navigation Component. Как при исользовании popBackStack() при наджатии на кнопку назад, вернуть последнее состояние MapView.