# Адаптер для фрагментов (FragmentPagerAdapter) в методе onCreate активности

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

Появилась проблема при попытке получить значение position в методе getItem адаптера. 
Имею класс пейджера фрагментов в активности с внутренним методом getItem:

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ...
    @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PagerFragment pagerFragment = new PagerFragment();
            pagerFragment.setPosition(position);
            return pagerFragment;
        }
    }
```

(Среди прочего) в результате выполнения кода ожидаю, что при смахивании будет вывод значения позиции пейджера. Собственно так и происходит, однако, при смене ориентации экрана код ломается и позиция не выводится. В связи с этим некорректно выводится контент моего фрагмента, который завязан на переменной position.
Как правильно получить переменную position после смены ориентации?
Заранее благодарен за ответы!

Comment: Ну... По идее вам надо просто там, где вы создаёте адаптер (в активити/фрагменте) сохранять/восстанавливать текущую страницу и в `onCreate()`/`onViewCreated()` устанавливать эту сохранённую позицию. Тогда он не будет каждый раз с 0 начинать. У вас ведь в этом проблема? Из вопроса не совсем ясно это.

Comment: Юрий, спасибо за ответ. Дело в том, что я передаю значение position в фрагмент, для вывода нужного списка. 
Проблема оказалась решена встроенным механизмом сохранения состояния фрагмента.  Я написал решение ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена путем использования механизма, сохранения состояния Fragment.
Внутри класса фрагмента в метод onCreate добавлено setRetainInstance(true);

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
```

Решение найдено здесь [Сохранить состояние Fragment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014959/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-fragment)